# It must indicate "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools, prestashop

Problem with google search console : structured data :" It must indicate "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating"

Comment: You need to provide more detail as to what you are asking for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Where does google say this?  In documentation?  In a tool?   What is your markup regarding this?

Comment: I'm taging google search console i'm not searching for a documentation i'm posting that problem for someone who know haw to solve it... Thx

Comment: This must be the structured data testing tool in Google Search Console.  You still don't say what structured data you are trying to test with it.   Please give us your URL or edit your question to add your markup.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking about errors from Google Search Console considering some properties of structured data. I recommend to take a look at Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data.

Comment: i'm using prestashop ...and i'm talking about an error from GoogleSearch Console...and nothing in that link can help to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, Google Search Console is telling you, that you should implement structured data. And from that link you can discover what structured data is and how to implement it. @benteber

Comment: I know haw to implement structured data but this time i dnt know why i get this error on Google search console @thomas nosek's

Comment: It's telling you in an unclear way that in order to get rich snippets you have to mark up one of those.